# How do you name/make something like this example (kinda fixed scrolling)

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, fixed

http://www.giampierocruceli.com/

How did this person achieve this? And is there any term so I can google that and maybe find a template or something.

Thanks.

Comment: https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/

Comment: on scroll you prevent the default behavior and make the scroll programmatically to the next section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just an on-scroll binding that overrules what should happen, then scrolls down to another element and said elements fill the entire screen. In my opinion and experience, these things are incredibly annoying to end users and extremely bug sensitive, but if you want I could write up an example for you... For googling purposes, try "Scroll full page" or something.

There are also plugins that take care of this, like this one: https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#3rdPage